# Can't draw on UI thread from incoming MSMQ event

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am using the class that the XAML is tied to:

```
<Window x:Class="TheWPFWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

I can draw anything in the constructor. In that class, I create a handler for when a message from MSMQ comes in:

```
AddHandler SomeQueue.PeekCompleted, AddressOf GetData
```

But when a message comes through, I think it is on a different thread than the UI (would make sense), and I cannot use the MSMQ message info to draw on the WPF UI in the GetData() Sub.

I have tried some Dispatcher() calls, but all I get is:

```
(at GetData) System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherObject.VerifyAccess()
   at System.Windows.Media.Media3D.ModelVisual3D.get_Children()
   at TheWPFWindow.GetData() in C:\users\yumi\project\TheWPFWindow.xaml.vb:line 271
```

I know the above actions will work if I can add the objects to the UI thread (they work when in constructor code), but I can't figure out how to tell the UI thread, and I might not even be able to find the UI thread!

I understand that Peek/PeekCompleted (which works) is asynchronous (on another thread), but shouldn't there be a way (in the same class) to use in from received by the incoming message in the application's graphics/UI thread?

It seems so simple, but is very hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke back onto the UI thread, something like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
{
    // to do something here...
});
```

or in VB.Net, I believe it would be something like this:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, New Action(Function() Do ... End Function))
```